# Updating every item in a table with Linq / C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to replace all urls containing `http:` with `https:` in the Seed() method of my EF Code-first configuration.  I have the following:

```
var context = new DbContext(); // contains public DbSet<Doc> Docs { get; set; }
var docs = context.Docs.ToList();  // dbcontext

foreach (var doc in docs)
{
    if (doc.ImageContent != null && doc.ImageContent.Contains("https:"))
        doc.ImageContent = doc.ImageContent.Replace("https:", "http:");
}
context.saveChanges
```

But whenever I run this (from my seed method in my database migration - so I can't debug as far as I know) - I get the following error:

```
System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities.
```

This error even occurs if I comment out SaveChanges.  The field is just a non-required string so I don't think validation is failing due to incorrect data type... what else could it be?

Comment: Apart of the question, could be possible you forgot `context.Entry(doc).State = EntityState.Modified`

Comment: @AlbertoLeón - just tried that and got the same error

Comment: Is there a paren after your saveChanges like this ... _db.SaveChanges();  Prob not the issue since you commented out that line.  You can also try with NuGet to get NLog to help with debug, that is how I debug the seeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change your code to this

```
foreach (var doc in context.Docs)
```

Since `var docs = context.Docs.ToList();` will pull all objects in memory and context is not able to track any change.

Comment: I can't believe this makes a difference. The objects fetched by `context.Docs.ToList()` are also tracked.

Comment: agree with Gert, unless you have used a projection, .Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; or             Context.Set<TPoco>().AsNoTracking()

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will take another look at this issue later today.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to perform an update on any records that match a certain criteria. Instead of pulling the whole list narrow your results sets.

```
var context = new DbContext(); // contains public DbSet<Doc> Docs { get; set; }

foreach (var doc in context.Docs.Where(d => d.ImageContent.StartsWith("https:")))
{
    doc.ImageContent = doc.ImageContent.Replace("https:", "http:");
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer because it only pulls docs from the database that really need update.